# Meaning of ちつまるつきり

Tags: meaning

[image]

What is the meaning of ちつまるつきり?
I have tried to look it up in a dictionary but found no result.
Google Translate translated it as small fuss. But how can I find the appropriate entry in the dictionary? Is it a phrase or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may be a little hard to tell in that font, but both of those つs are small.

In addition, it's not a single word but two - "ちっ" being a tutting sound, and "まるっきり" a common word that you should be able to find in any dictionary (it means "completely").

Comment: As Ben Roffey says, those "tsu" are small "tsu", which put a slight pause at that point in each word. Even if the font makes it hard to distinguish, as this one does, a good hint is to look where the comic decides to "break" a phrase. "ちっ" being alone on one line is a good indication that it is a word or sound on its own.